# Download files above web root and list them

Tags: php, directory, download, symlink

I am trying make a php script to list the files of a folder above my web directory...I follow a small thing I found here which talked about

a symlink pointing to /var/uploads

a Apache Alias directive Alias /uploads /var/uploads

I did both of these.

$myDirectory = opendir("/var/stuff/stuff/");

That directory there links to like when I go in winscp and click that folder it directs me to it....and when I run my script to list all files inside /var/stuff/stuff/ it lists what is in /home/stuff/stuff.

The thing is when I click the links that it produces I get a not found on the server
The requested URL /stuff was not found on this server.

Would someone please be able to assist me with this?

Comment: Wondering if I didn't ask this correctly...should I clarify something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the files are not under the root directory, you will not be able to download them directly, but What you can use for this issue is to create a downloader gateway.

I'll explain:

> 1. create a php script somewhere in your app, lets call it **downloader.php**
> 2. the downloader script would get a parameter, lets say: filename
> 3. now we could call the script like: ***`http://YOUR-URL/downloder.php?filename=file-to-download`***
> 4. in your *downloader.php* file you can get the file name, read it from the file system, then force it to be downloaded by out puting its content and configure the correct headers

I'm not sure if you still need that but, if you need more assistance I can help you more with some code samples

---

ideally you can use .htaccess to hide your downloader gateway script

Comment: Thanks! I don't really need it now, but I probably will in the future.